# OpenGL ES displaying HUD display Text can't be colored black on top of textured 3D objects

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, hud

This is a follow-up of this question on here
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/02/drawing-hud-display-in-opengl-es.html
It tackles on the HUD (heads up display) which is based on this tutorial >
[OpenGL ES displaying HUD display has no color on top of textured 3D objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681102/opengl-es-displaying-hud-display-has-no-color-on-top-of-textured-3d-objects)
I wanted to set the "Text" in color BLACK, but it is more complicated than what I thought.
Setting it to some other color other than black "glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);" is just fine.
I assume that the culprit must be in the Blending function "glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE);"
I experimented a lot of combinations with no luck. Has anyone experimented on this one on top of textured 3D in the backgrounds working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here!

Change in the Texture2D classes and  change stuff like Gray into RGB and the sizes of the allocations, plus a shawdow capability

http://majicjungle.com/blog/?p=191